# 3 balls are drawn from a bag contains 6 white balls and 4 red balls, what is the probability that 2 balls are white and 1 ball is red?

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

> A bag contains 6 white balls and 4 red balls. If 3 balls are drawn one by one with replacement, then what is the probability that 2 balls are white and 1 ball is red?

My answer came out as

$$\frac{18}{125}$$

What I did
Probability of getting a white ball= $6/10=3/5$
Probability of getting a red ball= $4/10=2/5$
Probability of getting 2 balls white and 1 ball red
= $6/10*6/10*4/10=18/125$

But the answer is $\frac{54}{125}$.
Why are we multiplying it by $3$?
Please someone elaborate this part

This is a gmat exam question.

Comment: Look at it this way, if you **don't** multiply by three, then your answer is the probability that we pick $2$ white balls and $1$ red ball **in that order**.

Answer (score 1):

You have to multiply by three because you can draw the red as either the first, the second or the third ball.

Answer (score 0):

This is a binomial experiment with $P(W)=\frac{6}{10}=\frac{3}{5}$. Apply the formula :
$$f(2)=C_2^3\cdot \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^2\cdot \frac{2}{5}=\frac{54}{125}.$$